# Automatizar preenchimento de tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:
id - email - chave_de_ativacao

Eu preciso popular a coluna chave_de_ativacao com uma chave aleatória (já tenho o script para criar essa chave), só que é tipo, 200 linhas, como posso ir populando cada um com sua chave de ativação aleatória (não pode ter repetida)?

Eu tentei com while, mas não deu certo e acabei deixando pra lá.

Comment: Não ser repetida vai depender do script que você já fez (que poderia ter postado). Para popular, poderia sim ser por `while`, buscando em um array a lista da referência dos registros que precisa inserir essa chave. Cole seu código, é importante vermos onde é que está errando. As vezes é bobeira que está errando, então é importante entender que está indo pela lógica correta.

Comment: Vai ter que colocar código, senão não temos forma de saber onde poderá estar o problema!